Why are these pin numbers backward?
I've been working on a board design, and decided that I wanted to move from a vertical header (Molex 0705430107) to a right angle header (Molex 0705550072).  The part I want seems to have a hidden "land mine" in the design which might cause reversal of the pin ordering.  This seems to be a departure from convention, as there are other parts, such as the similar [Molex 0705530107], as well as my original header, that put the first pin on the same side as the key.
Is there a reason for this change from apparent convention?  A possible oversight?  Is this a common problem that simply requires designers on their toes?

In my experience, I've seen many of boards that had to be re-spun because of pin numbering issues like this, or protos with blue wires hand-wired to a hanging connector :).  I always triple-check things like this since it's so easy to assume pinouts are like you think they are when they're not.

My best guess so far is that there is confusion on whether the footprint goes on the same or opposite side as the component.  The confusion, or simply lack of agreement, may be mine or someone else's.

I've used a connector family that had male, female, board2board, pin2pin, header, socket etc etc members, and of course two mating connectors should have mirror-image pin numbering. They didn't. Check the actual physical connectors in your hand, while observing the polarity markings, and their mating other half.
